# Reloading environment variables inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm writing a series of Ubuntu post-install scripts in order to install libraries and tools I need, one of this should install pyenv and latest python version using the former, the script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# clone the github repo
echo "Installing pyenv..."
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv

# update .bashrc
echo '# pyenv settings:' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# reload
. ~/.bashrc

# install python and virtualenv
echo "Installing python 3.5.1 + virtualenv..."
pyenv install 3.5.1
pyenv global 3.5.1
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install virtualenv
echo "pyenv has been installed with python 3.5.1 and virtualenv"
```

The problem is that the reload (`. ~/.bashrc`) seems to not work as expected,because I get:

```
python.sh: pyenv: not found
python.sh: pip: not found
```

I also tried with `source ~/.bashrc` and `exec $SHELL` but the problem remains.

How can I solve the problem?

ps: I'm executing the script with: `sudo sh python.sh`

Comment: nope, I checked the .bashrc before launching the script and it's ok

Comment: This is no bash script if you start it with: `sudo sh python.sh`

Comment: @wallyk I think he wrote he tried that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `~` is quoted, it does not expand to the user's home directory. Use this instead.

```
echo '# pyenv settings:' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=~/.pyenv/bin:"$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I would also rewrite it to look something like this:

```
cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.bashrc
# pyenv settings:
export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
EOF
```

However, you shouldn't be sourcing the user's `.bashrc` file; you don't know what else is in there, and you don't need to execute the whole thing, just the parts needed for the rest of your script. Replace `. ~/.bashrc` with

```
export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Comment: I rewrote the script but the problem persists :(

Comment: ok, by exporting only the variable that I need without the whole .bashrc reload it works! (I tried that previously but it failed... maybe due to ~)

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous to manipulate `~/.bashrc`, you don't need to either, unless you want something to be permanent.

Change

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

to

```
export PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

and the rest of the script will use the modified variables, even subshells.

**EDIT**

To make it permanent write it to a `~/.pyenvrc` and just modify `~/.bashrc` by appending

```
source ~/.pyenvrc
```

Comment: Difficult to do it from a script, unless you know how the `.bashrc` is laid out.